# Trying to change Timedelta to 0

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have the following dataframe with timedeltas:

```
0    -1 days +10:53:56
1      1 days 10:13:53
2      0 days 00:28:00
3      0 days 01:21:00
4      0 days 00:19:00
5    -1 days +23:59:59
6                  NaT
7      0 days 00:00:50
8                  NaT
9      0 days 00:38:00
10   -2 days +20:28:13
```

I'd like to change all of the negative values to 0.

I can filter out the negative by setting `df < pd.Timedelta(0)`, but I'm having trouble changing it to 0 days 00:00:00. I tried:

```
for time in df[df < Timedelta(0)]: 
     df = 0
```

but this doesn't do anything. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> I tried:
>
> for time in df[df < Timedelta(0)]:
> df = 0
> but this doesn't do anything.

It's even simpler than what you tried - no loop needed with the boolean indexing:

```
df[df < pd.Timedelta(0)] = pd.Timedelta(0)
```

If you have more columns in the data frame than just the Timedelta column, you of course have to specify the column, e. g. for a column label 1:

```
df.loc[1, df[1] < pd.Timedelta(0)] = pd.Timedelta(0)
```